# Unable to forwards ports after firmware update

Tags: router, port-forwarding, firmware

On a Netgear R7000 the new firmware v1.0.6.28 has broken port forwarding on port 80 because of there new functionality called "ReadyShare".

How to fix that?

P.S. It is very frustrating to see that a company like Netgear is coming out with a firmware update that break functionalities without any warning. I have 2 commercial websites down because of there crappy firmware.

Comment: Downgrade to the working firmware?

Comment: NetGear appear to class the R7000 as a Home router - http://www.netgear.co.uk/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/R7000.aspx

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, it is a home router???

Comment: If that's the same thing - it's the only "NetGear R7000" model I've found so far. It's on their site under "Home" products, not under "business" or "Soho". And ReadyShare is described as *"SHARE - Store, secure, and share your family’s files"* and it's also in the 'home' section - http://www.netgear.co.uk/home/discover/apps/readyshare

Comment: So you're running these "commercial" websites at home on equipment manufactured and marketed for the home environment?

Comment: @joeqwerty, Yes! Why not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded to firmware to v1.0.5.48 without success. I also downgraded to firmware to v1.0.4.30 without success. It looks like that ReadShare stays there and prevent port 80 to be forwarded.

Instead of being stock with Netgear firmware and problems, I decided to go with Open Source firmware. Up to now I installed DD-WRT which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing and re-adding the port forwarding entries?

From the release notes:

> If you have setup Port Forwarding, it needs to be re-configured after updating to firmware V1.0.6.28. Please remove all entries in the port forwarding table and add them back to reconfigure it.

You can also disable ReadyShare (or just the HTTP part) from the ReadyShare panel.

Comment: you are probably right. I red that message when doing the firmware upgrade but I was expecting that the upgrade would have flushed out my port forwarding which is didn't. Because it left my port forwarded config as is, I expected that it was not necessary to redo them. They also worked properly except for port 80. If the reconfiguration was only necessary for port 80, they should state that clearly. Now, I'm with dd-wrt and I don't plan to come back with the company firmware. DD-WRT is a little harder to configure but when done it feels like more flexible and more complete.Thumbs up!